# show animation views respectively

Tags: android, android-animation

I have six imageviews and textviews.
they are hidden at first(`android:visibility="gone"`).
I stored them in the two arrays : `arr_image_views` and `arr_text_views` .
I would like to show them respectively.

I made a FadeAnimationClass class.

```
private class FadeAnimationClass implements AnimationListener{

    private TextView txtview;
    private ImageView imageview ;

    public FadeAnimationClass(TextView t , ImageView i){
        this.txtview    = t ;
        this.imageview  = i ;

    }


    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        txtview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        imageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}
```

---

```
     animFadeOut    = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), android.R.anim.fade_out);

     animFadeIn     = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), android.R.anim.fade_in);  

     current_cat     = "1";

     arr_cat.add("1");
     arr_cat.add("2");
     arr_cat.add("3");
     arr_cat.add("4");
     arr_cat.add("5");
     arr_cat.add("6");
```

---

now, I want to start animation out  respectively :

```
    for(int i=0 ; i <arr_image_views.size() ; ++i){

        if(current_cat.equalsIgnoreCase(arr_cat.get(i))){
             animFadeIn.setAnimationListener(new FadeAnimationClass(arr_text_views.get(i),arr_image_views.get(i)));
             animFadeIn.setDuration(2000);
             arr_image_views.get(i).setAnimation(animFadeIn);
             arr_text_views.get(i).setAnimation(animFadeIn);                 
             animFadeIn.start();
             arr_image_views.remove(arr_image_views.get(i));
             arr_text_views.remove(arr_text_views.get(i));
                for(int j=0 ; j <arr_image_views.size() ; ++j){
                     animFadeIn.setAnimationListener(new FadeAnimationClass(arr_text_views.get(j),arr_image_views.get(j)));
                     animFadeIn.setDuration(4000);
                     arr_image_views.get(j).setAnimation(animFadeIn);
                     arr_text_views.get(j).setAnimation(animFadeIn);
                     animFadeIn.start();                         

                }
                break ;
        }
    }
```

but above codes shows an image view and a text view !

Comment: i think you should load the first animation for the first imageview and textview, and then in the onAnimationEnd() callback , you should launch the next animation for the second imageview and textview ... and so on until the last elements .

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem - is it with the animation not running properly? not all the images being displayed? Please clarify.

Comment: I'm just gonna guess that you're having problems because you're using animFadeIn (one instance) for animating multiple views (in a loop..) and that's why only your last views are displayed.